# Add Key on right click on folder with winreg in python

Tags: python, winreg

as the title mentions I want to create a script which allows to retrieve and display a folder when the user right clicks on the folder in question and opens it with my project. I saw a tutorial that talked about that but this one added a key when right clicking on the file but what I want is that when the user right clicks on the folder, that 'it has the possibility of opening this folder with my program. I Hope I'll find a solution hère.

I tried to search on the internet but I only found code which allows to add the program on the context menu when the user right clicks on the file but what I want is so that when the user clicks on the folder it can open with my program.